# Problem about the difference of two power

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

> Let $a>b>0$ such that $a+b=2$ and $\alpha\geq 1$ then we have :
>   $$a^{ab}-b^{ab}\leq \alpha(a^{\frac{ab}{\alpha}}-b^{\frac{ab}{\alpha}})$$

My try :

The problem is equivalent to :
$$\frac{a^{ab}-b^{ab}}{ab\ln(a)-ab\ln(b)}\leq \frac{(a^{\frac{ab}{\alpha}}-b^{\frac{ab}{\alpha}})}{\frac{ab}{\alpha}\ln(a)-\frac{ab}{\alpha}\ln(b)}$$

Hence it have the form (with $f(x)=e^x$):

$$\frac{f(ab\ln(a))-f(ab\ln(b))}{ab\ln(a)-ab\ln(b)}\leq \frac{f(\frac{ab}{\alpha}\ln(a))-f(\frac{ab}{\alpha}\ln(b))}{\frac{ab}{\alpha}\ln(a)-\frac{ab}{\alpha}\ln(b)}$$

But after this I don't know what to do...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't done the computation but have you tried differentiating with respect to $\alpha$ and showing that this is decreasing in $\alpha$ for $\alpha \ge 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $a>b>0$ and $a+b=2$, we have $a > 1$ and $b<1$, so $c:=a^{ab}>1>b^{ab}=:d$.

Then,

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha}
(\alpha(c^{1/\alpha}-d^{1/\alpha}) = c^{1/\alpha}-d^{1/\alpha}
 + \frac{1}{\alpha}(c^{1/\alpha}\ln c-d^{1/\alpha}\ln d) $$

and  $c^{1/\alpha}\ln c \geq 0$, $-d^{1/\alpha}\ln d \geq 0$.